# how to call WCF service method from Angular js

Tags: c#, angularjs

I created a WCF service and I am not able to call any method from my angular js script.

```
namespace jSonTest2.Service  
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
      RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class service:IService1
    {
        public DB obj = new DB();//object class which return string

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string IService1.JsonCall()
        {
            return obj.JsonCall();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------
namespace jSonTest2.DB_provider
{
    class DB//class 
    {
        public string JsonCall()
        {
            string str = "{name: 'Amit', marks: 97, distinction: true}";
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

//I created a WCF service and I am not able to call any method from my angular

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I created wcf service. and i am not able to call any method from my angular js script

Comment: Add more information to your question and format it correctly

Comment: You would call it like any other web service. Angular does not have one way for WCF and another way for other frameworks.

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: can this tag do something??

Comment: There are a load of tutorials showing how to do this.  Here's mine:  mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.7.htm  If you're having a specific problem or error, please put this in your question.